# Fedora refuses to install next to Win 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, fedora, dualboot

So I'm trying to dual boot Fedora 35 with Win 10 on the same SSD.

I have created free space on my disk worth 50 GB and tried to install Fedora from a bootable USB. The system always boots into live Fedora but when I try to open the 'Install To Hard Drive' program it appears next to 'activities' for a bit and then disappears. The same happens with 'Disks'.

I have secure and fast boot off, UEFI only, GBT SSD and the USB stick, I do not have RAID configured. I have tried making the USB bootable through Rufus, Fedora Media Writer, Ventoy, and through VM using livecd-iso-to-disk with the same result every time - the system boots but refuses to install (persistence did not work for me either).

I tried opening logs after the programs fail and this is what I usually get. https://ibb.co/T84cjWN

Unfortunately, I do not understand what these mean or how to fix them and the info on the internet is either too complicated or non-existent.

I have also tried installing Ubuntu. While the program for installation opened, when it came to choosing the disk, it froze.

Any advice is highly appreciated. I'm willing to provide you with any additional info, logs or reports that might help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some suggestions: (1) Update UEFI (2) Do not create "a partition" for Linux from Windows (you actually can't); use Windows tools to shrink its partition and get unallocated space for the installation. Unallocated space is NOT a partition. (3) make sure the ISO you downloaded is fine

Comment: Check if there is an UEFI firmware update available for your computer. The last line indicates that there might be a known problem with your current version.

Comment: @Robert - Thanks for the reply. I have updated my UEFI but the installer still does not open. Now I get this in logs: https://ibb.co/k6MjpNz.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Thanks for the reply. I have updated my UEFI but the installer still does not open. Now I get this in logs: https://ibb.co/k6MjpNz.

(btw: I have created 50 GB of free space, not partition, my bad, sorry. And the .iso is fine as it installs without a problem on my VM)

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so after a lot of struggle, I went and installed it onto my disk from my friends PC. I occasionally have some weird problems regarding storage but other than it is working just fine.